# The Ohm's law calculations of the parts do not agree with the whole

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement

In the circuit below, the Ohm's law calculations of the parts do not agree with the whole:

1. the voltage drops of the parts do not add up to the total voltage, and
2. the current does not calculate to be the same throughout the entire circuit.

Why? Actual VOM readings are in red and done with a digital VOM.

[image: Circuit anomaly]

Comment: What instrument was used to measure the voltages?

Comment: I assume you realize that I should have asked "Why?" before adding the last sentence, but I can see how that might be confusing.  Maybe I can still edit my original comment and put "why?" in the correct place.  The device I used is a E SUN DT830 Digital Multimeter.

Comment: Is there a resistance or loss between the components? Meaning if you check from the lead of 1 bulb to the other lead of the other is there a loss there? Is there a voltage drop between the last bulb and the battery? Voltage doesn't just disappear there is something that is measured when you measure both that is not being measured when measuring individually. If not then you have a bad meter.

Comment: Mine was a poorly-phrased request for instrument type and model number -- because a meter with an offset could give you results such as you see.  Voltage loss in the wires, or shooting at a moving target as the battery voltage decreases, is much more likely.

Comment: Forget about current, forget about Ohm's Law.  Your voltmeter measurements already violate KVL.

Answer (score 5):

the most probable causses for the discrepancies are the following:

1. The DT830 is not known as a quality meter. Inaccuracies in the readings are one cause of the problem.
2. You are drawing almost 300 ma from a D battery. At that level the voltage of the battery will tend to drop fairly quickly. Depending on how fast you take the measurements, the readings can vary due to that factor. Note that your own readings show a 0.2 drop in voltage from no load to full load.
   As a test of your meter try measuring the voltage of each of your D cells and compare it to the total voltage.

Comment: Barry Meter error would be gain or offset but even 5% would not account for these results. But I agree the battery could drop 2x (.4 to .2V) this much on start up as the load resistance starts at 11 Ohms (10.1+1) and rises to > 21 ohms but even this wont explain the errors

Answer (score 4):

> The Ohm's law calculations of the parts do not agree with the whole

Actually, there's a very plausible explanation which would mean that Ohm's law is alive and well, and does explain what you report.

(Note: I'm assuming that the bulbs have reached their steady-state "hot" resistances, so that those resistances don't change during the measurements. I'm also assuming that the battery voltage doesn't drop *significantly* during the measurements. It *will* drop, but I'm assuming that doesn't happen to a significant amount while measurements are being made.)

**Hypothesis: Additional wiring resistances**

Your diagram doesn't show additional resistances which *must* be present in your setup.

Let's look at just one area in your diagram as an example - the voltages across the two bulbs *together* and *individually*.

Here is your diagram again (so that readers don't have to keep scrolling up to the question):

[image: wiring diagram from the question]

Voltage drop across bulb 1 = 1.13V
Voltage drop across bulb 2 = 1.24V
Voltage drop across both bulbs **and the wiring between bulbs** = 2.6V
Therefore "unexpected" additional voltage drop = 2.6V - (1.13V + 1.24V) = 0.23V

Although the 10.2 Ω resistor value might not be very accurate (e.g. multimeter lead resistance is probably included in that, so the resistor's true value is likely lower) for now, let's use your approximate current value of (2.85V / 10.2 Ω =) 0.28A (to 2 decimal places).

Therefore the additional voltage drop between the two bulbs is only a resistance of (0.23V / 0.28A =) 0.82 Ω which is easy to believe, due to cable type / length / connection resistance etc.

---

The same reasoning explains why 2.85V (across the resistor) + 2.6V (across the bulbs) doesn't equal 5.9V - there are additional resistances (and therefore voltage drops) in the wiring / connections, which aren't included.

---

**Summary**: Go through the actual circuit hardware whose diagram you gave, measuring the voltage drops across not only the obvious parts, but *also* measure the voltage drop across every wire and connection of any kind.

You will find additional voltage drops which, when added to the voltage drops across the main components already given, I expect will show that the total voltage drops do all sum to the expected value.

Comment: **Ohm's Law only fails when there is human error,** e.g. from test method, lack of understanding of the model, time variance between readings or meter non-linearity from fault or lack of calibration.

Answer (score 3):

**Ohm's Law and KVL always applies** but the voltage drop is nonlinear with time due to thermal effects so bulbs **never match perfectly** and the voltages are never equal.

Bulbs are nonlinear PTC ( positive temp coefficient ) conductors that rise in R by 10x at rated power with temperatures of say 2500'K.

So R (hot/cold) ratio ~ 10:1 for bright warm white light (hot) and room temp (cold).

This means if you put two 6V bulbs in series with a 6V battery, you will **never ever** get 3V each.

The  bulb with even the slightest higher cold resistance heats up faster in temperature will rise in resistance faster and thus drop more voltage than the other bulb, resulting in a runaway condition where that bulb will have full power and the other about 10 %.  Putting a resistor in series as you have done reduces the balance difference between R cold= est. 0.5 Ohms and R hot est= 5 Ohms x 0.3A 1.5V

Although this is the extreme case where the bulbs are most sensitive to resistance changes at half voltage, it means your measurements probably changed while you were taking the readings.

Is it repeatable?  Is it stable?  Measure again.

If the load voltage is  5.9V @ 0.3A and the no-load Vbat=6.1V then the 4 battery cells have an internal resistance ESR = 0.2V/0.3A= 0.67 Ohms total.

## Can Ohm's Law be used for Li-Ion Batteries and light Bulbs?

**Absolutely.** It can, but I leave the proof to yourself, except it is demonstrated with an accurate model (Resistance of tungsten vs temp)  in simulation below.

Some naysayers try to prove Ohm's Law does not work for light bulbs as the resistance rises 10~20x depending on temp. rise. But it does work if you also include the {thermodynamics of} thermal time constants as shown in this simulation example, with [two idental power & voltage-rated light bulbs at 120V but one has thermally different rise times from insulation differences.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000155%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Av%20160%20144%20160%2096%200%200%2040%20120%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20160%2048%20112%2048%200%0Aw%20160%20144%20112%20144%200%0A181%20160%2048%20256%2048%200%20300.0000000000374%20300%20120%200.4%200.2%0A181%20256%2048%20352%2048%200%20300.00000000001495%20300%20120%200.08%200.08%0Aw%20256%2080%20256%2048%200%0Aw%20352%2048%20352%2080%200%0Aw%20352%20144%20256%20144%200%0Aw%20160%20144%20256%20144%200%0Ap%20256%2080%20352%2080%201%200%0Aw%20160%2048%20160%2080%200%0Aw%20160%2096%20160%2080%200%0Ap%20160%2080%20256%2080%201%200%0Ap%20112%2048%20112%20144%201%200%0Ax%20117%20-20%20275%20-17%204%2012%20300W%5Cs@%5Cs120V%5Cs400ms%5Csheat%5CsTr%0Ax%20294%20-19%20404%20-16%204%2012%20300W%5Cs@%5Cs120V%5Cs80ms%0A403%20272%20-96%20400%20-32%200%204_128_2_4866_160_0.1_0_1_10%0A403%20128%20-96%20256%20-32%200%203_128_2_4866_80_0.1_0_1_10%0A403%20128%20-160%20256%20-96%200%203_128_0_4353_40_0.00009765625_0_2_3_3%0A403%20272%20-160%20400%20-96%200%204_128_0_4353_160_0.00009765625_0_2_4_3%0As%20352%2080%20352%20144%200%201%20true%0Ax%20382%20115%20527%20118%204%2016%20click%5Csswitch%5Csand%5Cshold%0Ax%20138%20-177%20366%20-174%204%2012%20slower%5Csbut%5Cssame%5CsP,V,R%5Csrating%5Csfor%5Csboth%5Csbulbs%0Ax%20295%2060%20314%2063%204%2012%20fast%0Ax%20195%2059%20219%2062%204%2012%20slow%0As%20256%2096%20160%2096%200%201%20false%0Aw%20256%2080%20256%2096%200%0A)  The faster bulb always draws transfers more energy in the steady state.

> The same is true for the weakest Li-Ion battery in series. It is the first to burn out from over/Undervoltage and then rise in ESR either initially or due to thermal insulation differences in a pack and rising in ESR, over time as they become more mismatched in ESR.
>
> The same is true for **thermal runaway** in parallel LEDs with identical Rs voltage @85'C , that are mismatched thermally. ( *runaway can be avoided by thermal matching)*

Comment: let me run a quick simulation to prove that

Comment: Close approximation http://tinyurl.com/yxvdmqyk

Comment: Here using 1.05W@3V bulb and 1.1W bulb @ 3V http://tinyurl.com/y6etgsxk

Comment: Wow, give me a chance to digest all that.  Very sharp action diagram, but with my limited knowledge I don't see the + end distinguished on the circuits.  And right now the wife says dinner is ready...later!

Comment: a nitpick: saying that "Ohm's [l]aw always applies" is a heavy overstatement. No physical "law" known to human *always* applies. Every "law" is just a model - and every model is false, because every model is just an approximation - albeit some, as OL or KVL, are indeed extremely useful.

Comment: @vaxquis  I see no reason to doubt my conclusions or my statement. The readings can change from test to test reading as heat transfers between bulbs and changes the results. But Ohm's Law using simultaneous readings will not fail since this is DC and there is no interference from the DMM or VOM.  Do you have an experience to contradict this?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law ; a single quote is everything I should provide to you: "a law is limited in applicability to circumstances resembling those already observed, and may be found false when extrapolated." The notions of current, voltage and resistance are all approximations of values observed in physical processes assumed for a model. In many contexts they don't hold any relevance. As such, saying a statement that is concerning them "always apply" is simply not true.

Comment: Since it only becomes a Law when experimental data supports it after Peer review in the Physics community,  do you have any data to support your doubt? Or just a hypothetical one. Just remember the  time constants involved resemble a reactor but not. Ohm's Law still applies to nonlinear resistive parts like LEDs within the constraints of linear regression. over a limited range. I need data, to accept your doubt.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 -- Re "Is it repeatable? Is it stable? Measure again."
Yes very similar, e.g., voltage readings are 5.86, 2.83 across the resistor, 1.13 bulb, 1.24 bulb, and across the two bulbs 2.64.

Note: Using just a combination of 20 ohm and 10 ohm resistors in the circuit (no bulbs), the readings are 5.88v (which is across both resistors), 3.91v across the 20Ω, and 1.95v across the 10Ω.

Comment: Question for the mods - is it possible to down-vote a comment?

Comment: voice your opinion rather than a silent vote  @AnalogKid

Comment: @SanityCheck The last results indicate a difference of 5.88 vs 5.83 sum which indicates a 1% gain error difference.  and the 1st results indicate more than a 10% difference so there exists some other non-linearity in the readings. Time to calibrate the VOM. If one suspects an interaction with the meter reading, putting an RF cap across the meter would suppress any RF. that could be rectified due to long wires and give false readings.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 -- Alright, I must confess that I took a reading of the resistors while not in the same circuit and wiring, but mainly to determine the accuracy characteristics of the VOM.  I need to go over everything to include checking any voltage drop of the wiring & connections.

Comment: THat's OK Sanity CHeck. Ohm's Law violations are always measurement errors. It's just a question of WHY.  It's either wrong instrument, method,  time factor or human error.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 it's not about the measurments themselves. It's about the very notion of physics themselves. Physics still hasn't answered a question "what is time" and "how to measure time". As such, while a charge itself has shown to be a value that has a quantum measure (i.e. there exist a quantum of charge), there is still no real measure of current. Also, since a voltage has to be calculated across a distance, and we still don't know if space has any quanta, we're basically mixing apples and oranges here.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 You can't define I or V in strict terms, and R has no sense outside of being a factor of correspondence between I and V in a circuit with an ordered current flow. As such, Ohm's law (which, as has been discussed on EE previously and extensively, ain't even directly formulated by Ohm itself) is not a "law" in the sense most people think of it. It's an observation that holds under a specific set of axioms, and outside of them it holds no relevance. It's a pity you can't see that by yourself, EE75; I've always envisioned you as a very intellectually self-sufficient person.

Comment: tl;dr if you define R to be a factor of V/I, then R = V/I will always be true. That's not a physical law - that's a tautology, and a circularly referenced one at the same time. (resistance is the direct ratio of voltage to current - hence, a ratio of voltage to current has to be equal the resistance). Ohm only noticed the ratio of conductor's length to its resistance is essentially constant. Also, note the Johnson–Nyquist noise, quantum effects etc. - Ohm's law is only an averaged approximation, albeit a very good and useful one. Please, investigate the subject before arguing with me further.

Comment: I suspect you  have a healthy skepticism. I have a healthy experience of affirmation under a wide bandwidth of experience.  So until proof to the otherwise, I agree with. NIST https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2016/08/counting-down-new-ampere. FYI @vaxquis

Comment: @vaxquis  if you do not accept it  as a  Law as opposed to just a ratio or maybe to just an axiom or  lemma or a theorem  then I expect you feel the same about Newton's 2nd Law.a=F/m is also not a law using the same logic.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 as you seen yourself, it took a while to be able to fix at least some problems with the ampere unit. And actually, yes, Newton's law is exactly the same in this regard as Ohm's law. As soon as you plug in relativistic mass, as soon as you notice that acceleration is not directly measurable and that you have to derive it from differentiating velocity, which in turn has to be derived by differentiating the position, Newton's law is as useful as a hat on an elephant. https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/0705/0705.4455v1.pdf etc.

Comment: also, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32112/classical-limit-of-quantum-mechanics etc.

Comment: Yes I know all this, the assumption of my use of Ohm's Law "always" works assumed "here on Earth" not speed towards a Black Hole with my multimeter ready to do an experiment.  I think Gamma radiation and random space particles would blast thru my spacecraft windshield and my gold-plated resistor shield ready to do a test on Ohm's Law may not be functional at these relativistic speeds. I had already understood your point . I was hoping it would not be so pedantic yet it was truthful. Thanks for the discussion and reminding me I am so mortal.

Comment: Although, I believe it was Poincaré who developed Relativity before Einstein and he also knew around 1900 that the values in Maxwell's equations are Lorentz "covariant" *(the values in them transform)*
but their form is Lorentz "invariant": *(the same in different reference frames)*.

Comment: also the problem of measurement of quantum mechanics or the problem of energy in general relativity *is not solved yet* with particle and field theory but now I try not to get pedantic and stay in the practical world.

Comment: @vaxquis Gravity is a myth, the Earth sucks...

Comment: Resistance is futile

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 well, I've said out front *it was a nitpick* **chuckle**. You can't expect a nitpick to not be pedantic, can't you? ^_~ OTOH, since I was doing an actual research both in particle physics and quantum information theory during my MSc, those problems are actually quite relevant to me, for a multitude of reasons, *even here on Earth, just in a lab setting that's a **bit** more complicated than what OP was asking here about* ^_~ (yes, we Applied Physics guys can be a royal PITA sometimes... just image having a couple of us on an office party O_O)